# PowerShell Script Arguments Passed as Array

Tags: powershell

**EDIT:** I've changed the code here to a simple test case, rather than the full implementation where this problem is arising.

I am trying to call one Powershell script from another, but things aren't working out as I'm expecting. As I understand things, the "&" operator is supposed to expand arrays into distinct parameters. That's not happening for me.

**caller.ps1**

```
$scriptfile = ".\callee.ps1"
$scriptargs = @(
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
)

& $scriptfile $scriptargs
```

**callee.ps1**

```
Param (
    [string]$one,
    [string]$two,
    [string]$three
)

"Parameter one:   $one"
"Parameter two:   $two"
"Parameter three: $three"
```

Running `.\caller.ps1` results in the following output:

```
Parameter one:   a b c
Parameter two:
Parameter three:
```

I think that the problem I'm experiencing is  `$scriptargs` array is not expanded, and is rather passed as a parameter. I'm using PowerShell 2.

How can I get caller.ps1 to run callee.ps1 with an array of arguments?

Comment: I should also note here that I have used the EchoArgs utility from the PowerShell Community Extensions, and the arguments appear to be correctly formatted.

Comment: You defined deploy args as an array are you attempting to invoke the string as an expression

Comment: I am attempting to build the arguments as an array as seen on [this blog post](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/) under the heading "But what if I want to build the arguments to pass in my script?"

Comment: It looks like your question actually has little to do with MSDeploy and more to do with dynamically invoke PowerShell commands that are stored in strings. I suggest editing your tags, and maybe even trimming down your code so it's shorter and to the point.

Comment: You might look at the additional options available with configuring parameters here, but note what version of PowerShell you are using: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When invoking a native command, a call like `& $program $programargs` will correctly escape the array of arguments so that it is parsed correctly by the executable. However, for a PowerShell cmdlet, script, or function, there is no external programming requiring a serialize/parse round-trip, so the array is passed as-is as a single value.

Instead, you can use [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to pass the elements of an array (or hashtable) to a script:

```powershell
& $scriptfile @scriptargs
```

The `@` in `& $scriptfile @scriptargs` causes the values in `$scriptargs` to be applied to the parameters of the script.

Comment: Note that splatting requires PowerShell 3.0 or later.

Comment: @Sam: MS says 2.0 at least -> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the variables as a single object, you need ot pass them independently.

This here works:

```
$scriptfile = ".\callee.ps1"
& $scriptfile a b c
```

So does this:

```
$scriptfile = ".\callee.ps1"
$scriptargs = @(
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
)

& $scriptfile $scriptargs[0] $scriptargs[1] $scriptargs[2]
```

If you need to pass it as a single object, like an array, then you can have the callee script split it; the specific code for that would depend on the type of data you're passing.

Answer (score 1):

Use Invoke-Expression cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Expression ".\callee.ps1 $scriptargs"
```

As the result you'll get :

```
PS > Invoke-Expression ".\callee.ps1 $scriptargs"
Parameter one:   a
Parameter two:   b
Parameter three: c
PS >
```

Comment: This works, with the added benefit that you don't need to know what the arguments will be (or how many of them there are) at design time.

Comment: Invoke-Expression has a number of painful errors with quoted arguments, and also can be a security hole (if you don't carefully check the input).

Comment: I'd definitely prefer Emperor XLIIs solution over this one.